# Bootstrap switch doesn't work on localhost and Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I've got weird problem with Chrome browser that I use for development purposes. I've created dashboard with [Bootstrap Switch plugin](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch) and everything was fine till another system reboot. For some reason, that one plugin stopped styling properly.

[image: styling error]

No errors in dev console.

I thought it was related to cache (reloaded page, reloaded without cache, cleared cache) - nothing.

Checked with IE and... it works OK.

Suspecting cache to be the problem, I've changed the folder where I keep the website. Still nothing.

All Chrome addons disabled - nothing.

Next thought was some kind of collision with other scripts, so I removed one after another until I was left with whatever is required to run that plugin - and still nothing!

I tried with Firefox and it works okay.

I accessed the website I got already deployed on server, where it was still working and the plugin ran okay. But when I downloaded it to localhost - the problem reappeared.

Finally I've discovered, that whenever I access my website locally using http://localhost - it somewhat crashes the styles. Changing to http://127.0.0.1 fixed the problem - or rather appeared to be a workaround.

[image]

Any ideas why is this happening?

HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">


        <div id="panel_control_manual" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">TEST</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Panel content 
              <input type="checkbox" checked>

            </div>
          </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(":checkbox").bootstrapSwitch();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any `htaccess` configs? Have you tried specifying full url till resource?

Comment: @Justinas - didn't change any htaccess entries, still - shouldn't that affect other browsers as well? It's server setting AFAIK. What do you mean with "full url till resource"? CSS/JS files?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Chrome's DNS cache by browsing to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click "Clear host cache"?

Comment: @Mark Full url means with server name like `http://example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @Justinas - nope, didn't help either

Comment: @KhalidT. - cache cleared but no result... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mark -Did you find the solution? One of our clients hit the same issue.